# how to create a substring without using malloc()

Tags: c, malloc, free

How can I implement a substring function such as the following that returns the substring but without using `malloc()` in the process so I don't have to worry about freeing the associated memory elsewhere in my code using the `free()` function.  Is this even possible?

```
const char *substring(const char *string, int position, int length)
{
    char *pointer;
    int c;

    pointer = malloc(length+1);

    if (pointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (c = 0 ; c < position -1 ; c++)
        string++;

    for (c = 0 ; c < length ; c++)
    {
        *(pointer+c) = *string;
        string++;
    }

    *(pointer+c) = '\0';

    return substr;
}
```

**UPDATE: 30 DEC 2012**

Having considered all the answers and comments it's clear that essentially what I'm trying to do is create a dynamically sized array (i.e. the substring) and that is not possible in C without somewhere along the way having to use some kind of `malloc()` function and a subsequent `free()` call on the substring pointer or without the aid of a garbage collector.  I attempted to integrate the `libgc` garbage collector as kindly suggested by @elhadi but so far have [not been able to get this to work in my Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080426/can-the-libgc-library-be-used-on-ios).  So I have opted to stick with using the following code with `malloc()` and `free()`.

```
char * subStr(const char* srcString, const int offset, const int len)
{
    char * sub = (char*)malloc(len+1);
    memcpy(sub, srcString + offset, len);
    sub[len] = 0;
    return sub;
}

int main()
{    
    const char * message = "hello universe";
    char * sub = subStr( message, 6, 8 );
    printf( "substring: [%s]", sub );
    free(sub);
}
```

Comment: do you want to modify the original string?

Comment: @perreal I do not want to modify the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a local buffer (an auto array) and a function like this:

```
void substr(char *dst, const char *src, size_t loc, size_t len)
{
    memcpy(dst, src + loc, len);
    dst[len] = 0;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
const size_t size = 3;
char buf[size + 1]; // this is an auto array, it will be "freed" at the end of the scope
substr(buf, "abcdFOObar", 4, size);
```

Always ensure the buffer is at least `len + 1` bytes long to avoid buffer overflow errors.

Comment: what if the size of the substring will vary?

Comment: @NSDigital What do you mean by "if it will vary"?

Comment: I think my reasoning is that I'd prefer not to have to declare a buffer everytime I want to get a substring, e.g. I often use `substr()` as an argument to a logging function `log("some info",substr(someStr,3,4));`

Comment: @NSDigital In that case, you have to use `malloc()`. Or redesign your code.

Answer (score 6):

I see two options:

If you can destroy the source string (usually a bad thing):

```
{
    string[ position + length] = 0;
    return & string[ position ];
}
```

*Note: (see Cole Johnsons note: free no longer works on the returned pointer!)*

If you can't modify the source string:
Modify your methods signature so that the caller has to worry about it:

```
const char *substring(const char *source, char* destination, int position, int length)
```

And put the modified string into destination (and return it).

And do not even think about this:

```
const char *substring(const char *string, int position, int length)
{
    char *pointer;
    int c;
    static char modifiedString[256];
 ...
    return modifiedString;
}
```

Using a static variable inside the function for the modified results...
(This is not thread-safe (not re-entrant!) )

Comment: Would I still have to use free() as some point in the caller?

Comment: If you change the pointer (fist example), free will no longer work.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char *substring(const char *string, char *substr, int position, int length)
{
    int c;

    for (c = 0 ; c < position -1 ; c++)
        string++;

    for (c = 0 ; c < length ; c++)
    {
        *(substr+c) = *string;
        string++;
    }

    *(substr+c) = '\0';

    return substr;
}
```

calling function...

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char substr[10];

    substring("hello! World", &substr[0], 2, 4);
}
```

Comment: @NSDigital, you can use this function without having to define a local variable by using a compound literal: substr((char [size+1]){0}, str, pos, size). If you don't want to retype the crude compound literal definition every time you can use a macro that always provides the first argument.

Comment: Thanks @JensGustedt, could you provide some more detail? How would I then access the value of the substring? Could i use `printf()` to see it?

Comment: I like the macro approach @JensGustedt but in some cases in my code the substring length is determined by an expression e.g. (myVariable+position) and so the compilere gives the error "Variable sized object may not be initialized."

Comment: @NSDigital, yes, if this is a variable length array (VLA) you'd have to define this as an uninitialized variable, there would be no way around this.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is:

```
typedef struct vstr_t {
     char *s;
     int   len;
} vstr_t;

#define vstr_set(d, l)                  \
    ({                                  \
        vstr_t vs = {.s = d, .len = l}; \
                                        \
        vs;                             \
    })

#define vstr_fmt_arg(vs) (vs).len, (vs).s

int main()
{    
    const char *message = "hello universe";

    printf( "substring: [%.*s]\n", vstr_fmt_arg(vstr_set(smpl + 6, 8)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes of course, all the MAX_SZ will be allocated by the compiler, if you want something dynamic, you should use C++ string.

Comment: yes of course, if you need some thing dynamic should use c++ string or stay in c and use a garbage collector

Comment: @Martin james, you should know that malloc also is not a thread safe

Comment: thread safe is, if you have two thread which call the same function substr at the same time, you will have a strange sub string as the work on the same buffer on the same time

Comment: Can someone demonstrate a threadsafe version of a substring function?

Comment: @Martin James: of course, it is dependant on how you compile, with/without thread, the compiler will choose thread-safe/not thread-safe malloc. so when compiling with -pthreads, it'll be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a garbage collector, you allocate the memory the first time, the garbage collector will free the memory when no needed.
you should include

```
#include "gc.h"
```

in the main you should make something like

```
GC_INIT();  /* Optional on Linux/X86;*/
```

and your substr function is:

```
char *substr(const char* buffer, const int offset, int len)
{
    char sub = (char*)GC_MALLOC(len+1);
    memcpy(sub, buffer + offset, len);
    sub[len] = 0;
    return sub;
}
```

you should link with `libgc.a`

Comment: How does the GC know when the object is not needed? Presumably when the caller has finished executing?

Comment: You can compile GC to support threads and to be thread-safe, see: hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/simple_example.html  or http://linux.die.net/man/3/gc

Comment: @NSDigital It is very dangerous to edit a string. What if its a string literal editing the same is not allowed and it will result into a segmentation fault.